# Using windows API in DLL

Tags: c++, windows, api, dll

I have written a class for easy sound synthesis in C++. This class (let's name it foo) uses the waveOut API. I import winmm.lib and windows.h for the waveOut API to work.

Now I want to export my class foo to a DLL, to use it in C#. There are a lot of definitions from, for example mmeapi.h (I suppose that that's included when I'm including winmm.lib, but I'm just guessing). How can I use the functions and definitions from winmm.lib?

Comment: What's the problem you're having?  Are you getting compiler errors?  Runtime errors?  Are you asking how to export a class in a DLL?

Comment: if the question is how to call c++ API from c#, use DLLImport: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, and add up to the existing comments, you can also create a COM DLL, and load it in c#. This way you can use the objects you created, and not just call a function.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I realize now the question is a bit vague. I can't compile because my code use a lot of definitions from mmeapi.h (for example HWAVEOUT, WAVEFORMATEX, etc.) I can copy these in my class, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong if I do that.

Comment: @TCS Nice! I didn't mention it, but that is indeed something I'm trying to do.

Comment: This has been done.  Download the naudio library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way by far to do this is to compile a mixed mode C++/CLI DLL. It is called mixed mode because it mixes managed and unmanaged code.

You can compile your existing C++ class into a mixed mode DLL. Then to export the functionality as a managed class, wrap it up in a C++/CLI ref class. Once you've done that you can add it as a reference in your C# program and it's all good!

Comment: Sounds good! Do you know a link to a tutorial, or any other way to get me started? I've googled but I can't find one simple enough to understand for me.

Comment: This was the first hit I got on my websearch: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes

Comment: You're a hero! (And appearently, I'm a lousy googler... In my defense, it was late.)

Comment: Well, I haven't got it worked out (haven't found the time), but hopefully I will work it out when I'm free. Thanks for your help!